# Android preferences theme

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Does anyone know how I can set the the margins so the PreferencesActivity appears centered?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChLbo.png) is the result I'm getting.

[Desired theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGnq.png) I'm trying to achieve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using PreferenceActivity.

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
      }
    }
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you can't set margins for an `Activity`. Activity always covers the whole screen. You should instead do one/couple of:

1. Stick with the `Activity` approach and:

   1. Get `ListView` by `PreferenceActivity.getListView()` and set its `LayoutParams` using `ListView.setLayoutParams()`. You can pass `LayoutParams` specifying desired margins for the `ListView`.
   2. Set background of `ListView` above using `View.setBackgroundDrawable()`.
   3. Set background of `PreferenceActivity` like above.
2. Switch to a `Dialog` for example.

FireFox uses the the second approach. It utilizes `PreferenceScreen`, `PreferenceGroup` and `*Preference` (e.g. `CheckBoxPreference`) classes for the whole *Settings* dialog. The `PreferenceScreen` indeed uses a `Dialog` as the preference container.